# mysqldump not exporting data, only schema

Tags: mysql

I am running `mysqldump` as follows:

```
mysqldump -u root --password=secret -d dbname > output.sql
```

When I review the output, I only have the schema. However, if I connect using the same exact settings and query, there is plenty of data:

```
mysql -u root --password=secret -D dbname 
mysql> select count(*) from account;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      230 |
+----------+
```

Based on the official docs, it seems I am using mysqldump correctly. I'm on OS X and this is my mysql info:

```
» mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 8.0.19 for osx10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-d` option means not to write the table contents. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-syntax) says:

> `--no-data, -d`
> Do not write any table row information (that is, do not dump table contents). This is useful if you want to dump only the CREATE TABLE statement for the table (for example, to create an empty copy of the table by loading the dump file).

Remove the `-d` option and you should get all the table contents.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
mysqldump --user=<username> --password=<password> --result-file=<path_to_backup_file> --databases <database_name>
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-syntax) says that if you don't list any tables, it will dump all tables. Why is your syntax necessary?